# Bootsrap 4 columns behaving as a table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to recreate a table with the bootstrap 4 grid. I got it to behave as a table with this CSS code

```
.data-table{
    display : table ;        
    padding : 0em; 
}

.data-table > .row{
  display : table-row ; 
}

.data-table > .row > * {
  display : table-cell ; 
  white-space : nowrap ; 
}
```

The `.data-table` is in the `.container` div.

I set the columns class as "col-auto" , so the width of the columns is arranged according to the data inside it. All of this together works pretty well, but the problem is when I try to get some of the columns to not show up in medium to small devices, with bootstrap 4 "d-none d-lg-block" class,  the whole table gets all buggy. But this only happens if I set this class in two columns that are next to each other, I have it setup up like this :

```
<div class "col-auto d-none d-lg-block"><!--code--></div> 
<div class "col-auto">--code--</div> 
<div class "col-auto d-none d-lg-block"><!--code--></div>
```

It works pretty well.

So, I want to know how I can fix this problem, and what I can do differently.

Comment: I think the best approach for small screens is to scroll the table horizontally instead of hiding columns. To do that just add `overflow-x: auto` to the table's parent element.

Comment: Yeha,  I also think that is the best approach, but my superior want's me to hide the columns. It works, but not the way I'm doing for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that you are re-writing the display attribute so it doesn't work as defined by bootstrap. What I would do is I would use the typical bootstrap [table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/), add an extra class to the cells I want hidden and use @media to hide them.
Assuming the class is named md-hide the css would look like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   .md-hide {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.